# How do I change the Classtype of ModelExpression in TagHelpers?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to create a Tag Helper which accept some property names of a specific model.

```
public class DataTableColumnTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; } //This is for ViewModel
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

By default, above `For` is binding to the `ViewModel`. Is it somehow possible to bind it to another class?

I first tried to do it via a generic type parameter with `DataTableColumnTagHelper<TModel>`, but `<data-table-column<SomeModel>>` is not valid syntax.

I currently have it have it working this way:

Tag Helper:

```
public class DataTableColumnTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "p";
        output.Content.SetContent(For.Metadata.PropertyName);
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public class UserGroupViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public UserGroupTableItem TableItem => null;
}
```

View:

```
<data-table-column for="TableItem.Id"></data-table-column>
<data-table-column for="TableItem.Label"></data-table-column>
<data-table-column for="TableItem.PermissionQuantity"></data-table-column>
```

My goal is to remove the `TableItem` property, since it's only a dummy to make `ModelExpression` work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered using a partial view instead of a tag helper? Seems like it would be a better fit for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

From your example; `<data-table-column for="TableItem.Id">`, razor assumes you mean `Model.TableItem.Id`. Razor will generate code like this to set the value of each `TagHelper`'s `ModelExpression` properties;

```
ModelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(ViewData, __model => __model.TableItem.Id);
```

([Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/e49de3ea57df8c29a27c338cb2d8546406cd4572/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions/ModelExpressionPass.cs#L26))

If you prefix your attribute value with `@`, the generated code drops the implicit `__model.` so you can bind the `ModelExpression` to any c# expression;

```
@t = Model.TableItem;
<data-table-column for="@t.Id">
```

I can't think of a way to make it any simpler, while still being strongly typed.